# Do I need to physically host my website in separate countries for SEO?

Tags: seo, web-hosting, local-seo

I run an ecommerce store that is hosted in Ireland, and ranks ok with google.ie

The market for this comapny is the Republic of Ireland and the UK.

Is it beneficial for me to have a UK hosted version of my site (.co.uk) to rank higher in google.co.uk (and other localised search engines of course).

If so, how would I prevent the site from being punished for duplicate content?

Thanks in advance for any assistance on the above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the accepted answer of this question [SEO implications of hosting a UK-based site on an EC2 instance based in Ireland](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1478/seo-implications-of-hosting-a-uk-based-site-on-an-ec2-instance-based-in-ireland?rq=1) you have link pointing to usefull resources and answers to your question http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/03/working-with-multi-regional-websites.html

Ih this page, I think you have your answer

> **Dealing with duplicate content on global websites** 
>   Websites that
>   provide content for different regions and in different languages
>   sometimes create content that is the same or similar but available on
>   different URLs. This is generally not a problem as long as the content
>   is for different users in different countries. While we strongly
>   recommend that you provide unique content for each different group of
>   users, we understand that this may not always be possible for all
>   pages and variations from the start. There is generally no need to
>   "hide" the duplicates by disallowing crawling in a robots.txt file or
>   by using a "noindex" robots meta tag. However, if you're providing the
>   same content to the same users on different URLs (for instance, if
>   both "example.de/" and "example.com/de/" show German language content
>   for users in Germany), it would make sense to choose a preferred
>   version and to redirect (or use the "rel=canonical" link element)
>   appropriately.
>
> Do you already have a website that targets multiple regions or do you
>   have questions about the process of planning one? Come to the Help
>   Forum and join the discussion. In following posts, we'll take a look
>   at multi-lingual websites and then look at some special situations
>   that can arise with global websites. Bis bald!
>
> Written by John Mueller, Webmaster Trends Analyst, Google Switzerland

Hope this helps

Comment: brilliant, thanks alot for pointing me in the right direction, helps a bunch - cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Some web hosting companies provide RIPE IP Failover blocks. It allows you to choose the geolocation of each IP block: IE, FR, DE, ES, EN, PL and so on (all IP Failover blocks route to your server). Thus you'll improve the SEO of your projects in major search engines.

Then no need to have a website URL like

- www.mywebsite.com/ie/home
- www.mywebsite.com/uk/home

because you know from which route your visitors came from so you display the related content: 
visitors who reach the website through IP Failover A see www.mywebsite.ie, visitors who reach the website through IP Failover B see www.mywebsite.co.uk.

- Easier to maintain: only one server.
- Cheaper: only the cost of the second domain name and few IP Failover.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Many thanks @Jules, I had never heard of this technique will have to investigate it further. Is it RIP or RIPE (or both!)? As I notice it coming up in my searches.

Comment: @noelmcg: you're very welcome. Yes it's RIPE, sorry for my mistake. My post has been corrected.